# "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds is exceeded" when I override toArray() function

Tags: php, laravel, api

I needed to override function `toArray()` to check does user has proper permission to get specific column, so I created this function:

```php
public function toArray( $options = 0 )
{
    if(!auth()->user()->hasPermissionTo('users.show.email')) {
        $this->hidden[] = 'email';
    }

    // etc ... 

    return parent::toJson($options);
}
```

but then when I use `User::Get()` in controller to get list all of users I don't get any result, but after 60 seconds I get:

```
[2019-04-06 23:18:33] local.ERROR: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\starter\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Arr.php:162)
[stacktrace]
```

Everything is fine if I don't override `toArray()` function.

Comment: Do you have a recursion issue? does memory spike during execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the last line you're calling `parent::toJson()` method, which internally [calls `$this->jsonSerialize()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1097), and this one [calls `$this->toArray()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1113) — your overridden function, thus heading to infinite call-loop.

In your overridden function you should be calling `parent::toArray()` instead.

Comment: I just realized it 5 seconds before you answered xD, but anyway thank you for answering.